# Export data from datatable using primefaces 2.0

Tags: jsf, datatable, export, primefaces

I have a page where I load some data into a datatable and provide three buttons for export to pdf, xls and csv.  I used the same sample code Primefaces has in its web page:

```
<h:commandLink>  
   <p:graphicImage value="../resources/images/Excel.png" />  
   <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="grdAudit" fileName="ApplicationLog" />  
</h:commandLink>
```

When I click the commandLink, I get the following exception error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException
at org.primefaces.component.export.PDFExporter.export(PDFExporter.java:45)
at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:94)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:84)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:773)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:296)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:783)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1248)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute 
(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run
(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet
(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter
(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun
(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run
(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs
(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute
(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute
(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass
(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass
(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass
(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass
(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass
(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
... 29 more
```

Apparently, this class is missing: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException but I do not know how to get it, where to install it nor why the error is showing up.  Any idea?

Comment: Ok I just found the answer.  First, the user's guide of primefaces 2.2.1 says on page 12 that you need a specific versions of the POI and iText libraries for the exporting.  After you have downloaded the correct versions and include them in the project, the exporting should work.

Answer (score 1):

First, the user's guide of primefaces 2.2.1 says on page 12 that you need a specific versions of the POI and iText libraries for the exporting. After you have downloaded the correct versions and include them in the project, the exporting should work.

Answer (score 1):

- iText-2.1.5.jar
- poi-bin-3.7-20101029.zip

Download both and import it in your project and it will solve your error.