# Export Dynamic HTML to PDF in JSF , PrimeFaces?

Tags: javascript, jsf, pdf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to convert a HTMl file into a PDF file using Primefaces.

I am familiar with [JavaScript Exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786113/export-html-page-to-pdf-on-user-click-using-javascript).

Is there a way to have the same in JSF,Primefaces.

Need reference document or links which such functionality in JSF,Primefaces.

Comment: @HugoTunius I had seen the [Primefaces Showcases](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/exporter.jsf) and tried it worked fine with datatable,but i want to do export for a html file into a PDF, which i am unable to find how

Comment: @HugoTunius [Exports how i had done is by following these guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812811/export-data-from-datatable-using-primefaces-2-0), i am new into JSF and Primefaces. I am working on an application with these technologies .So, i need some help out to reach my goals

Comment: @HugoTunius Can u help me out!

Comment: @BalusC can u help me out!

Comment: No I am sorry I have no experience with Primefaces.

Comment: This is not really related to Primefaces, you need a library that does the HTML to PDF conversion, something like iText.